# what is required for automation in plantation?

Tags: gpio, python, sensor

What i want to do is when the moisture of the soil gets decreased i just want to give water to the plants or if i can just get a notification about the moisture would be fine. I have very little knowledge about this things.
I have raspberry pi and moisture sensor module but i don't know about the connections and working of the moisture sensor module. What is the analog and digital in that module?. How can i get the levels of moisture using python script? Is there any other modules which i need to purchase?

Comment: Have you seen this http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-raspberry-pi-moisture-sensor-to-monitor-your-plants--mac-52875

Comment: @SteveRobillard I dont wont to use breadboard. Any suggestions w/o it?

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/?q=perma%20proto&

Comment: There seem to be a whole series of questions here.  I think you need to research more on the www and come back with a more targeted question.

Comment: As joan says, there is a series of questions here.  This is not a discussion forum, it is a Q&A site.  Also, in future, be specific about what you are referring to.  I am sure there is more than one moisture sensor module in the world that can be connected to a pi.